# .Net 4.7.1 silent install remote Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have created a PowerShell script to remote into a list of computers and to install silently .net 4.7.1.

The install works on 32 bit systems but on 64 bit systems it fails midway with error code 16389.

This is the command I use.

```
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {CMD /c \\$Using:name\C$\temp\NDP471-KB4033344-Web /q /norestart} -ErrorAction Stop
```

I was able to put this command`C:\temp\NDP471-KB4033344-Web /q /norestart` into a bat file and run the file on the local machine and it installs, but if I execute the bat file remotely it gets half way through and then I get the same error.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Solved the issue with the help of this.
https://superuser.com/questions/640883/net-framework-4-5-remote-install-via-powershell